# IP to location + local time?

Tags: php

Currently I've been using http://www.geoiptool.com/ but I can't get the local time.  I don't know what to do to get the local time.

Can someone help me out, to display location + local time? I have a mail app and I try to display IP in location + local time.

Comment: What data does this tool give you? Do you have the location (country, district) or just the coordinates? Does it give you the time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is not real answer to your question but can help you to properly understand how inaccurate this method is.

**Please, read this answer as a side note.**

Yes, it's OK to offer or set location/time for your users. But you should provide country/time selector for them also. Some of IP's can not be resolved properly (anonymous proxy, borrowed IPs from other countries (my case), continental IPs (like group "Europe", "Asia", etc), etc.

My case shows how this approach may be wrong.

When I've tried ipLocator from geobytes.com I've got this:

[image]

My IP address has been resolved to:

- Location: **Romania**
- Time offset: **+0200** (at the moment DST is active so it's `+0300`)

Real problem is that my location **is not** `Romania`, and my time offset is `+0100/+0200`.

Look this picture:

[image]

Red arrow shows my real location. Info in black box shows correct values for my real location. Well, wrong location is not such a big problem for users, but wrong local time is very annoying thing.

Yes, I know, that's not what you're looking for. But you should not fix users location and/or local time because it can be wrong approach. IPv4 address is certainly not something accurate to get real info about user.

Also, I found that ipLocator doesn't follow DST rules and using that time offset (image #1) will show wrong local time during Summer (for countries/regions/provinces which consider DST).

Comment: wow you put a lot of work into that answer thank you for the information.

Comment: @Kyle, not really. That's just two screen-shots and couple of text lines (couple of minutes of my time). However, I've voted up your question to get more attention of community.

Comment: so do you get banner ads offereing to "Meet local girls in Bucharest"? :) http://xkcd.com/713/

Answer (score 3):

Geobytes will give you the offset:

http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&IpAddress=64.34.119.12

Or in an XML format (you might need to view source to see it):

http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=64.34.119.12

This will give you the offset, just add/subtract the offset to GMT/UTC.

Comment: Just because i found this the other day and got really excited at the liberal license and costs: http://simplegeo.com Youd probably want to use the Context api for this.

Comment: Yeah the only thing i was disappointed in is that it PHP library they created relies on some PEAR packages. For me this is nonsensical because im normally in a Symfony or Zend PRoject and between the two ive already got 1 or 2 libraries that implement the same functionality (sfWebBrowser, Zend_Http_Client/Zend_Oauth_Client, Zend_Uri). So i had to spend about an hour or so changing the deps over to Zend. No big deal... just annoying :-)