# How to get the correct time from client location to server

Tags: java, web-services, web

I have clients spread across in different countries. However, my server is in a different country. Then at the server how can i get the time at my client. I know i can use scripts to get the system time on the client machine. But this would fail if the time is set incorrectly on my client's machine.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: define "time" if you don't want the system time

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you're trying to achieve here, or what the client looks like. How much information from the client *are* you willing to trust?

Comment: If you don't trust that the client machine has the correct time I see no other option than asking the user.

Answer (score 2):

```
// if you try to print it, it will return something like:
// Sat Mar 21 2009 20:13:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
// This time comes from the user's machine.
var myDate = new Date();

//Pass myDate to the server by loading something with an ajax call
$(someSelector).load('serviceurl.com?d='+myDate)
```

Use a serverside script to process the data received as $_GET['d']

to check if the time is right you can use a trid party service but that is just more likely to get you wrong data then the system time on clients computer. See this for details [IP to location + local time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828228/ip-to-location-local-time)